# Multi-threaded udp server/client

Tags: c, udp, fork

I just created a little reliable file transfer using udp but it only handles one client. So I thought about using fork() to get the server to handle multiple clients. But, i don't really know how to proceed. For now, I know I don't need to change the client side and the server is the one that will do the dirty work. Any thought/ideas on how to tackle that problem is greatly appreciated.
Ps. here is how I started:

```
 void sigchldAction(int sig) {
 while (waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG) > 0) {
     ;
 }int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 return;
} //This is my function that waits for all the processes
```

Here is my server:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int port_number, socket_fd;
    port_number = atoi(argv[1]);

    signal(SIGCHLD, sigchldAction);

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
 (const void *)&optval, sizeof(int)) < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    bzero((void *)&serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port_number);
    if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,
         sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    pid_t child_pid;
    while (1) {
    child_pid = fork();

    switch (child_pid) {
        case -1:
            perror("Fork() Failed. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        case 0:
            process_request(socket_fd);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        case 1:
            close(socket_fd);
            break;

    } 

}
    close(socket_fd);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Then my process_request function takes care of any incoming data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using UDP you don't have a connection; it's a connectionless protocol.

If you're going to fork, you'd need to do what ftpd does and tell the remote client to send the forked child packets on a different port than the original one (and of course have the child receive on that port).

Comment: So in udp it's not possible to have all the client running on the same incoming port?

Comment: @fabricemarcelin - You can but it is going to get complicated.  You can get the source addresses (the clients) with recvfrom() and separate them that way.  But if you are forking children on the same port what's to stop the first child from reading the initial datagram from client #2?  TCP sort this out for you because accept() creates a new socket beneath the covers.

Comment: @Duck - Quick question though. If I fork at the socket, how will I know the new port number to pass as a parameter to the client?

Comment: @fabricemarcelin - Your server requests an ephemeral port by specifying 0 as the port number in bind.  You can then get the assigned port by calling getsockname().

Answer (score 1):

You're better off avoiding `fork()`, and simply distinguishing the clients based on their source address.

The basic approach to take is to take all of your variables that currently describe the application-layer connection (eg. current file, current position within the file, client address) and hoist those into a `struct`.  You then create one instance of this `struct` per client.

Use `recvfrom()` rather than `recv()` to listen for incoming packets.  This will supply the client's address (note that address in this sense should include the client's port number) - you can then look up the appropriate instance of the per-client `struct`.

Comment: Can you please provide some pseudocode or point to an example like this. Thanks